# Ubuntu 16.04: mouse pointer and display flickering, but theres no unknown display, so what do?

Tags: 16.04, display, amd-graphics, flicker, mouse-pointer

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop Asus K45DR which use AMD HD7460 graphic card. Already tried some suggestion on internet that i should turn off any unknown display on system settings>displays>unknown display but i cant find the unknown display, only the built-in display. So what do?

Comment: Oh hey, i just found out when i charge my laptop its stop flickering but when its not, well it does flickerinng. Do you have any explaination?